# C: Not counting spaces and new lines

Tags: c

I have the following source code to count blank spaces, new lines and characters in a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    int fd;
    int b=0, nl=0, c=0;
    char ch[1];
    fd=open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);

    while((read(fd, ch, 1))>0)
    {
        if(ch==" ")
            b++;
        if(ch=="\n")
            nl++;
        c++;
    }
    printf("no of blanks %d\n", b);
    printf("no of new line %d\n", nl);
    printf("no of characters %d\n", c);
}
```

The result is like this:

```
no of blanks 0
no of new line 0
no of characters 24
```

My text.txt file's content is:

```
hello world
hello
world
```

Number of charactes is right (it includes spaces and new lines). But why are the result of variables `b` and `nl` wrong?
PS: I'm new to C, but have a little practice in C++.

Comment: `(read(fd, ch, 1)) > 0` looks like you're throwing away information.

Comment: `char ch[1];` looks strange. Maybe just `char ch;`

Comment: The minimal fix is `ch[0]==' '` and `ch[0]=='\n'` or even short `*ch==' '` and `*ch=='\n'` :-)

Comment: stdio would be better as it use buffering

Comment: As you advised, I changed char ch[1] to char *ch and compared like *ch=='  \n' but that didn't work. PS. the read function 2nd parameter should be a reference, that's why it is used  the array ch[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h> // or just include <string> it may vary depending on the compiler you use
int main(){
int fd;
int b=0, nl=0, c=0;
char ch[1];
fd=open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);

while((read(fd, ch, 1))>0)
{
if(strcasecmp(ch, " ") == 0) //you need to use strcasecmp() instead of == for strings
b++;
if(ch[0] == '\n') //you can also check like this.
nl++;
c++;
}
printf("no of blanks %d\n", b);
printf("no of new line %d\n", nl);
printf("no of characters %d\n", c);
}
```

Comment: if I use strcmp, there is a warning while compilation with gcc:  warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 if(strcmp(ch, " ")==0). But it works though

Answer (score 2):

> if(ch==" ")

should be

> if(ch==' ')

And same for the other comparison, `"\n"` should be `'\n'`

The double quotation is for string. Use single quotation for character.

And yes you should use `fopen` instead of low level `open` call.

```
int ch;
FILE *fp=fopen("text.txt", "r");

while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if(ch==' ')
        b++;
    if(ch=='\n')
        nl++;
    c++;
}
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: @alk you're correct. It'd be better to use `fopen` and change the `ch` from array to single character variable. I edited that.

Comment: I can't use fopen cause in this task I should use System calls and in the previous task I have already used fopen for the same aim to count spaces and new lines. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the space `" "` and newline character `"\n"` in single quotes and declare `ch` as `char`.

Answer (score 0):

In C language,you can't directly compare two strings. 
You have to use strcmp(char *str1,char *str2) or strncmp(char *str1,char *str2,ssize_t size).

If you will directly compare the strings it will return 0,which is why blanks and newlines are not incrementing.

Try this correction.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
 int fdesc;
 int blanks=0, newlines=0, characters=0;
 char buf[1];
 fdesc=open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);
 while((read(fdesc,buf, 1))>0)
 {
  if(strcmp(buf," "))
   blanks++;
  if(strcmp(buf,"\n"))
   newlines++;
  characters++;
 }
 printf("no of blanks %d\n", blanks);
 printf("no of new line %d\n", newlines);
 printf("no of characters %d\n", characters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all ur feedback I managed to fix the code and finally it looks like that :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(){
int fd;
int b=0, nl=0, c=0;

char ch[1];
fd=open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);

while((read(fd, ch, 1))>0)
{
if(ch[0]==' ')
b++;
if(ch[0]=='\n')
nl++;
c++;
}
printf("no of blanks %d\n", b);
printf("no of new line %d\n", nl);
printf("no of characters %d\n", c);
}
```